# Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable M1 Macbook (Android studio)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, apple-m1

When attempting to run the emulator on android studio I receive the Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable error message. I'm using the most up to date android studio for ARM processors. Additionally, when i restart android studio the devices now permanently states "Loading devices". I just got this laptop.

Things I have tried:

1. Restarting PC (hahaha)
2. Restarting android studio
3. Reinstalling android studio
4. Trying old versions of android studio for arm devices.
5. I'm using Android 12 (s) preview

Please help :D

Comment: Attaching the medium [link](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/my-journey-to-setup-android-emulator-for-m1-macbook-pro-b8365321b3e7) here for Android emulator on Macbook M1.

Comment: Android Emulator is not in a good shape for M1 Macs right now. I will suggest using the physical devices instead of Emulators until google officially releases a stable version of the emulator.

Comment: Have you got the solution yet . I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 23):

[Installing Rosetta](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211861) will fix your issue.

In **terminal** run the command:
`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Comment: It helped . But why Rosetta , tho android studio has been made to work on arm ?

Comment: Android Studio is ready but some platform tools like adb are not I think and AS is using them

Comment: How to install Rosetta: https://osxdaily.com/2020/12/04/how-install-rosetta-2-apple-silicon-mac/

Comment: i hate that this was the problem. This took me 6 hours to find

Comment: not android studio issue, but this resolved similar problem on Mac M2 xcode 14.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I have met that kind of issue when compiled a java program with intellij idea.
Installing the XCode fixed my issue.